# spring security rest java confiigs base auth

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, basic-authentication

I try to add basic auth to my REST Sevice. Using Spring MVC 4 + Hibernate. My service provides JSON api. User info store in database. But unfortunatly I can not do this by myself.
I`m looking for full sample code with java spring configs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First you have to try something, read spring security documentation and post your code if you are blocked.

Answer (score 0):

There is few tutorials I've found so far:

http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/08/spring-restful-web-services.html

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-tutorial-part-2-java-based-configuration

Unfortunately we use Spring-data-mongo and we don't use Hibernate, so can not help you much.

Thy to implement code from these tutorials and if there are some particular questions, people here at Stackoverflow (including me) will be glad to help you.

Also take a look at [Spring docs](http://spring.io/docs) (there are good tutorials too) and [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/).